# How to get single row from resultset

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a sql query that returns two rows. I have used BeanPropertyRowMapper to retrieve query results and I want to use first row and assign specific values to pojo. How do I retrieve single row from resultset

Answer (score 4):

For a single row, you can use this `JdbcTemplate#query` overload, for example

```
JdbcTemplate#query(java.lang.String sql, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse, java.lang.Object... args)`
```

Which means

```
jdbctTemplate.query(
      sqlStatement,
      resultSet -> {
         final MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
         pojo.setOne(resultSet.getString(1));
         pojo.setTwo(resultSet.getInt(2));
         return pojo;
      },
      statementArgument1, 
      statementArgument2
);
```

Or, if you want to maintain the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
      sqlStatement, 
      new BeanPropertyRowMapper(MyPojo.class),
      statementArgument1,
      statementArgument2
);
```